# Regex to reject names ending in non-letters except dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a regex that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the text provided is a valid first/last name:

```
let letters = `a-zA-Z`;
  letters += `àáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšž`;
  letters += `ÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð`;
  const re = new RegExp(`^[${letters}][${letters} ,.'’-]+[${letters}.]$`, 'u')
  return(name.match(re));
```

So far, I'm able to ensure it only validates names that actually start with a letter and do not contain numerals or any special characters other than dot, hyphen, or comma. However, it still rejects names like `Jo` and `Xi`. I understand it's due to the three separate $-blocks. But the blocks are there to ensure the name doesn't start with a non-letter or end in a non-letter other than dot. How should I modify my expression to accommodate this?

Also, is there any way to *shorten* this expression without compromising its range? I still need it to cover extended Latin characters.

Comment: Use `let re = /^\p{L}(?:[\p{L},.'’-]*[.\p{L}])?$/u` if you are targeting ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the minimum length of the word is 2 chars, you could use a negative lookahead `^(?!.*[ ,'’]$)` to assert that the string does not end with the characters that you would not allow and leave out the last `[${letters}.]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvepdJ/1)

If the minimum length is 1, you could use another negative lookahead `(?![ .,'’])` and add the dot as well so that a single dot is not allowed at the beginning and then use the single character class that contains all allowed characters.

```
^(?!.*[ ,'’]$)(?![ .,'’])[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'’-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvepdJ/2)